# Cumulative Layout Shift with image from CMS

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to fix image layout shifting in a grid with different image size as follow

[image]

In that case, I don't know the initial `width` and `height` of the picture. I only add a `width` in `vw` on the image container.

The current implementation is as follow:
A custom image component to serve an image with the width size only. I never know the height of the image but I can fix the width, then the image will adapt the width of its container.

```
/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-img-element */
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useIsomorphicLayoutEffect } from '../../hooks/useIsomorphicLayout';

interface IIntrinsicOptimizedImage {
    img: string;
    size: number;
    alt: string;
    className?: string;
    noLazy?: boolean;
}

export const IntrinsicOptimizedImage: React.FC<IIntrinsicOptimizedImage> = ({
    img,
    size,
    alt,
    className,
    noLazy,
}) => {
    const [url, setUrl] = useState('');

    const _className = className ?? 'img';

    useIsomorphicLayoutEffect(() => {
        const dpr = 2;
        const w = (window.innerWidth * size) / 100;
        const url = `${img}&w=${w * dpr}`;
        setUrl(url);

        return () => {
            setUrl('');
        };
    }, [img]);

    return (
        <img
            className={_className}
            src={url}
            alt={alt}
            decoding="async"
            loading={noLazy ? 'eager' : 'lazy'}
        />
    );
};
```

As I said before, the image comes from a CMS and I will never know the intrinsic height of the image.

So, is it possible to avoid CLS in that particular case?

Many thanks

Comment: Could you describe more what you want the layout to be? And show your code and what you have tried so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth Yep, sorry for that, updated! The grid need to be flexible, the width of the image is always the same (constraint by its container) and the the height will adapt in order. The thing is need to avoid layout shift without knowing the height of the image.

Comment: Is the image that you have shown the sort of layout you want? (or are you looking for a more masonry type layout?)

Comment: Yes, it's coming from the current project layout.